# How to rollup rows in an RDD based on column and get sorted values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to get the below output from the input file by reading as an rdd.

rdd contains:

```
key1, val1
key1, val2
key2, val1
key2, val2
key2, val3
```

output will be `Map[String, List[String]]`

```
Map[String,List[String]] = Map(key1-> List(val1, val2), key2 -> List(val1,val2,val3))
```

I have done it by reading the df, but how to do it directly on rdd?

```
val abc: Map[String, List[String]] = data.rdd
      .map(row => (row(0).asInstanceOf[String], row(1).asInstanceOf[String]))
      .collect
      .zipWithIndex
      .map({ case (key, index) => (key._1, key._2, index) })
      .groupBy(_._1)
      .map({ case (k, v) => (k, v.sortBy(_._3).map(_._2).toList) })
```

Comment: when you need output in rdd then why are you reading as dataframe and converting to rdd? just read it as rdd

Comment: if i read it directly as an rdd then above code is failing

Comment: is that the file data in your question that you say to be rdd? and can you share how you are reading data to dataframe?

Comment: `data` is a dataframe.  and i am reading as :  `val data = spark.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("charset", "UTF8")
      .option("delimiter", ",")
      .load(file)`

Comment: I have tried to answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `sparkContext`'s `textFile` function to read as `rdd` and then do the necessary parsing and follow the same footsteps as you have followed.

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("path to the csv file")

val result = rdd.zipWithIndex().map { case (line, index) => {
  val array = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
  (array(0), array(1), index)
}
}.groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(x => x.toList.sortBy(_._3).map(_._2))
  .collectAsMap()
```

This should give you your desired output as `result` is

```
Map(key2 -> List(val1, val2, val3), key1 -> List(val1, val2))
```

Comment: great to hear that @Sanjay :)